# How can i call a PHP Query using JQuery and Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two columns, the first column is the draggable and got multiple words, and the second column is the dropabble, the words from the first column will be dropped into the second column.

And i would like to save this transition into my database table, how can i do that?

I'm using JQuery UI

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".event").draggable();

$(".drop").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var id = ui.draggable.attr("id"); //get the name from the draggble
         var targetid = event.target.id ; //get the name from the dropabble

        alert(id);
        alert(targetid);
    }
});
});
```

And i would like to call a function with a PHP query, everytime that a word is dropped into the dropabble box.

I just want a simple example.

Comment: You can use AJAX to call some PHP.

Comment: @Steve you want to save that word in the database right

Comment: Yes, i would like to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code may it is works for you...

```
    //php file... saveThis.php
    <?php
    $word=$_POST["word"];
$secondWord=$_POST["secondWord"];
    $insert="your insert query here";
    mysql_query($insert);
    echo "saved";
    ?>
```

do this stuff in javascript or JQuery

```
$.post("saveThis.php", {word:passYourWordHere ,secondWord:YourSecondWordHere }, function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

thank you, i hope this is helpful